# What is the proper way of sizing and formatting picture icons?

Tags: html, css, image

So I am trying to figure out what is the best way to get all of the pictures on a webpage to load as quickly as possible. I would just like to know what the best method is if I have.

Lets say a *1600x900* image that I wanted to size down to *890x500*

**Method 1**

`<img src="myPic.png" height="500" width="890"/>`

**Method 2**

Resize the image in Photoshop or whatever and use: `<img src="myPic.png"/>`

**Method 3**

Resize the image in Photoshop and use: `<img src="myPic.png" height="500" width="890"/>`

**Method 4**

Using CSS to resize an image with some combination of the above... (not sure if this really works but I figured I would put it up there for the sake of completeness)

**What is the Best picture format?**

This is another thing I have been on the fence about, while GIF's help consolidate the file size, you do sacrafice quality. PNG's are always good because they have the best quality, but the file sizes are relatively large. As for JPG's I have steered clear of them because I feel like they are fairly big files yet the quality isn't that great, and my uses with them are limited because they *MUST* have a background.

Just want to know all of your thoughts!
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try lossless optimization, or intelligent lossy optimization such as that offered by http://kraken.io

Comment: You have two questions here. Please focus on one, and create another question if needed.

Comment: PNGs vs GIFs, just remember that older versions of IE don't support PNG transparency, should that be of concern to whatever project you're undertaking.

Comment: just a note for PNG support in IE, its 2013 now...

Answer (score 0):

Your first option must always be to resize the image beforehand to make sure the image send to the users is as small in size as posible. This is the best option perfomance wise, so your page will load faster.

If you still want to resize your image, because perhaps It's an image an user can upload and they might not upload an image with the correct dimensions, you should resize the image using css, so that all your css is in a single file and thus is easier to maintain.

As for the format:

- Gif for none transparent images
- Jpg for pictures only
- Png for images with transparency

Answer (score 0):

- Even if you set `width="0" height="0"` **the browser will still load your 1600x900 image**.
- **Performance-wise** you can just **help your browser** defining size using `width` and `height` attributes.
- **Best** image format? **Depends** on your needs.
- After cropping/resizeing your image In PS go to **<kbd>Save for Web</kbd>** and play with the compressions and preferences keeping always an eye to the image **size**/vs/**quality**.

---

Regarding **.jpg**, I don't understand your thoughts. They are **perfectly good**.

- a raw .jpg image (nature) 800x600 best quality = **555KB**
- same image for web quality 60 = **118KB**
- Same image for web 60 and blur 0.5 = under **100KB** (yep, the blur trick)

Differences? Almost unnoticeable.

---

- You need perfect alpha opacity + transparency? **.png** <sub>(plugin support for older IE browsers)</sub>
- You need transparency and don't care about pixelated borders **.gif**
- You need an basic background (pattern)? **.gif**

Comment: .jpg's I find don't look as good on the web, especially when you are using it as a relatively large image. As for the `Save for Web` Thing, I learn something new everyday, I always used that for GIF's but I never knew you could change it to use it for png's as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 5** - `myPic-small.png` is resized,

```
<a href="myPic-big.png"><img alt="..." src="myPic-small.png" /></a>
```

Few more notes:

1. for **JPG** do not use 100% quality, 85% - 90% gives good quality and size.
2. use **PNG** when image do not have many colors (size can be even smaller when JPG), when you need lossless image format, or you will need to edit it in future, or need transparency.